# Steps to install magento 2.4 install on Mac

Tags: magento2, installation

Is there any way we can install magento 2.4 install on Mac OS ?

Comment: https://ddev.readthedocs.io/en/stable/users/quickstart/#magento-2

just copy paste and you are ready to go ;) DDEV is php dev environment which works perfectly for magento2

Comment: Well, any solution for docker in Mac (Apple silicon) is messed up, for personal use, I'm using the Dbngin for database and Redis, and PHP in brew (shivammathur tap) I've been working with these stacks for 2 years without issue

Answer (score 0):

1. Use MAMP in mac for Magento 2.

https://www.dckap.com/blog/how-to-install-magento-2-on-macbook/

2. You can try docker method also.

https://www.linkedin.com/pulse/macbook-tutorial-guide-setup-magento-2-docker-mahesh-karekar

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but its a paid software.

Comment: Try docker or else you can install each services like apache mysql separately.

Comment: Yes, that's the only option.

Answer (score 0):

I assume by you saying that it is "a paid software", you are referring to Magento Cloud version (aka now called Adobe Commerce), and not the open-source version.

I'd like to reiterate what @mahesh-v said by using Docker.  We've been using it at our company for both the open source and cloud versions and it's been working great.

I'm a fan of using Docker vs. installing things directly into macOS simply to keep the system running as clean as possible.

[Mark Shust is a ***fantastic*** resource](https://github.com/markshust/docker-magento) that helped me immensely when I first started building out our sandboxes. The GitHub link also has a link to an M.Academy video set that is very helpful as well.

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

I recommend you to use this one https://docs.warden.dev/environments/types.html#magento-2

It is really easy to setup and start working on Mac.
Other option is to try Mark Shust Magento docker repo.
https://github.com/markshust/docker-magento
There is a free course how to use it. Good luck.